# Second and third monitor only detected after reboot - Kubuntu 20.04

Tags: kubuntu, hdmi, monitor

I tried almost everything to force detection of my monitors. E.g.

```bsh
# ctrl-alt-F1
sudo service sddm restart
# F2
```

```bsh
xrandr --auto
```

It does not matter what I try. My monitors will only get detected after reboot.
This happens when I plug out my Monitor HDMI cable and then put my PC into sleep mode. Then when it wake up and I insert my HDMI cable again the monitor will not get detected. It does not matter which HDMI Output I choose.

Does anybody has a solution that not involve rebooting my system?

Answer (score 0):

Actually what was working was plug the HDMI cable back to your PC and then go to sleep mode. And then after waking up the monitor should be detected again. However, very strange bug. In this case also all processes was close like it would be a reboot even when it was only a sleep.